# Create searchable archives from a static HTML/CSS onepage site with daily archives

Tags: html, css, archive, searchable

We are looking to hire a developer to build a custom solution for us, but before that we basically need to know what questions we should be asking, since none of us have any experience with programming. We have a website that is a daily listing of coffee news that is then archived, with each HTML file representing an entire day of news. What we're looking for is some sort of search functionality that would allow specific results to be displayed, rather than the entire page the results came from.

Here is the website in question: http://dailydose.coffeetalk.com/

Answer (score 0):

Typically you will have each news clip stored in a database. Then you want the developer to write a functionary to query that database for find news clippings of interest to the users.

The HTML only serves as a template to display this data you retrieved from the database.